# jquery load using $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web-services

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            /* HTML Menu Example Code */
            $('#GlobalNav')
                .load('http://navservice.intranet.hpr/api/gethtml', function(){               
                  initmenu();
              });                     
         });
    </script>
```

How do I convert this to sth like this? except the data type is plain html coming from the webservice?

```
          $.ajax({
                url: "Common.asmx/InsertClient",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{BizName:'" + BizName + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(msg) {
                    $('#status').html('Id: '+msg['d']['Id']);

                }
            });
```

Comment: The web service returns unordered list items (html) that i need to style using some menu plugins like ddsmoothmenu etc. So i need to load the returned html into a div and then use than use that div's id/class to call ddsmoothmenu function etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://navservice.intranet.hpr/api/gethtml',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (html) {
        $("#GlobalNav").html(html);
    }
});
```

... Or `$.get`:

```
$.get('http://navservice.intranet.hpr/api/gethtml', function (html) {
    $("#GlobalNav").html(html);
});
```

Keep in mind that `.load` callback function accepts the HTML retrieved from the server, so you may be able to keep using that depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: the navservice is a totally different domain than where I am calling from. navservice lives in a separate server and I am calling from a SharePoint site, which is in a totally different farm. is that maybe why i am not getting anything back?

Comment: Yep, you won't be able to do that due to the same origin policy.